# data grouping according to relevant values in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

the data is in 15 minute interval:

```
Time               Value
2010-01-01 00:15   3
2010-01-01 00:30   2
2010-01-01 00:45   4
2010-01-01 01:00   5
2010-01-01 01:15   1
2010-01-01 01:30   3
2010-01-01 01:45   4
2010-01-01 02:00   12
2010-01-01 02:15   13
2010-01-01 02:30   12
2010-01-01 02:45   14
2010-01-01 03:00   15
2010-01-01 03:15   3
2010-01-01 03:30   2
2010-01-01 03:45   3
2010-01-01 04:00   5
..........
..........
..........
2010-01-02 00:00
```

Typically there will be 96 points.

According to the values, we may notice that the values from 00:15 to 01:45 are close to each other, and from 02:00 to 03:00 they are close to each other, and from 03:15 to 04:00 they are close to each other.

Based on the "close to each other" rule, I want the data to be "grouped" into 3 parts:

- 00:15 to 01:45
- 02:00 to 03:00
- 03:15 to 04:00

Please consider that the data could be random, and could be grouped into more than 3 parts according to the rule defined above, but maximum should not be more than 10 parts. And the grouping must honor the time sequence, for example, you cannot just put 00:15/02:30/04:45 into 1 group because these 3 points are NOT consecutive.

Please give some thoughts how to implement it in t-sql.

**updated:**
The value could be:

```
Time               Value
2010-01-01 00:15   3
2010-01-01 00:30   2
2010-01-01 00:45   4
2010-01-01 01:00   5
2010-01-01 01:15   1
2010-01-01 01:30   3
2010-01-01 01:45   4
2010-01-01 02:00   12
2010-01-01 02:15   13
2010-01-01 02:30   4  --suddenly decreased
2010-01-01 02:45   14
2010-01-01 03:00   15
2010-01-01 03:15   3
2010-01-01 03:30   2
2010-01-01 03:45   3
2010-01-01 04:00   5
..........
..........
..........
2010-01-02 00:00
```

for these kinds of situation, we should not group 02:30 separately, because we want the group size has to be at least 3 points, and we will put that point (02:30) to the previous group (from 02:00 to 03:00).

Comment: It might help if you were clearer about a definition for "close to each other". What is the greatest numerical difference you would consider "close"?

Comment: Also defined "grouped".  Does grouped just mean a report like the bullet list?   Is there a rule for minimum of maximum number of groups?

Comment: What if I have a sequence such as, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. Each one is "close" to the one before it, but 9 may not really be considered close to 1. The hardest part of programming is usually figuring out exactly what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: sorry I did not explain my question clearly. The main purpose of this is to identify the consumption periods. Typically, everyday from 0AM to 8AM, the consumption will be failrly low, from 8AM to 4PM should be quite high, and from 4PM to 8PM should significiantly drop, and from 8PM to midnight should be fairly low. "close to each other" means the difference between neighbouring point should be more or less the same, "less than a delta", take my sample values for example, we can tell the delta should be 5, so it will end up with 3 groups, and finally we can apply the group boundaries to our biz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question changed so much, here is a new answer to the new question, I only included the code part.

```
declare @t table(time datetime, value int)
declare @variation float
set @variation = 2
set nocount on

insert @t values('2010-01-01 00:15',3)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 00:30',2)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 00:45',4)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 01:00',5)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 01:15',1)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 01:30',3)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 01:45',4)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 02:00',52)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 02:15',5)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 02:30',52)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 02:45',54)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 03:00',55)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 03:15',3)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 03:30',2)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 03:45',3)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 04:00',5)


declare @result table(mintime datetime, maxtime datetime)
a:
delete @result

;with t as
(
select *, rn = row_number() over(order by time), log(value) lv from @t where datediff(day, time, '2010-01-01') = 0
), a as
(
select time, lv, rn, 0 grp from t where rn = 1
union all
select t1.time, a.lv, t1.rn, 
case when exists (select 1 from t t2 where t1.rn between rn + 1 and rn + 3 and 
lv between t1.lv - @variation and t1.lv +@variation) then grp else grp + 1 end
from t t1 join a on 
t1.rn = a.rn +1
)
insert @result
select min(time), max(time) from a group by grp

if @@rowcount > 10 
begin 
    set @variation=@variation + .5 
    goto a 
end

select * from @result
```

Result:

```
mintime                     maxtime
2010-01-01 00:15:00.000     2010-01-01 01:45:00.000
2010-01-01 02:00:00.000     2010-01-01 03:00:00.000
2010-01-01 03:15:00.000     2010-01-01 04:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 7):

Declare and populate testdata:

```
set nocount on
declare @result table(mintime datetime, maxtime datetime)
declare @t table(time datetime, value int)

-- variation is how much difference will be allowed from one row to the next
declare @variation int
set @variation = 5     

insert @t values('2010-01-01 00:15',3)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 00:30',2)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 00:45',4)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 01:00',5)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 01:15',1)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 01:30',3)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 01:45',4)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 02:00',12)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 02:15',13)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 02:30',12)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 02:45',14)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 03:00',15)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 03:15',3)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 03:30',2)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 03:45',3)
insert @t values('2010-01-01 04:00',5)
```

Code:

```
a:

;with t as
( -- add a rownumber
select *, rn = row_number() over(order by time) from @t
), a as
(-- increase group if current row's value varies more than @variation from last row's value
select time, value, rn, 0 grp from t where rn = 1
union all
select t.time, t.value, t.rn, case when t.value between 
       a.value - @variation and a.value +@variation 
       then grp else grp+1 end 
from t join a on 
t.rn = a.rn +1
)
insert @result
select min(time), max(time) from a group by grp


if @@rowcount > 10 
begin 
    -- this will activate if more than 10 groups of numbers are found
    -- start over with higher tolerance for variation
    set @variation=@variation + 1 
    delete @result
    goto a 
end

select convert(char(5), mintime,114) + ' to ' + convert(char(5), maxtime,114)
from @result
```

Result here:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/110891/declare-and-populate-testdata

Comment: This is definitely what I want! You are absolutely the champion! Altough I need to modify it to deal with different "variation" because actual data will end up with different variation, for example, the value might look like: 0.005, 0.004, 0.006, 0.003, 0.007 etc, or 5222, 3212, 4522, 4221, 5521, 1100, 998, 4221 etc.

Comment: Sorry, one last thing, I updated the main post, please refer ot it. The main idea is that the group size has to be least 3, which means each group must have at least 3 points.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Bonus points for using the Stackoverflow Data Explorer to show your code running!  Nice work!