# In what case would the use of a T-SQL GOTO statement be acceptable?

Tags: sql, t-sql, coding-style, goto

In a "religious" discussion about formatting of Microsoft T-SQL code, I questioned whether or not the GOTO statement was still available in T-SQL syntax.  In 13 years of using T-SQL I have never had occasion to use it, and indeed didn't know if it existed.  After a brief search of the documentation and to my consternation it does indeed exist!

My question is this:

Is there **at least one case** where GOTO statements would yield a solution that **performs** better than one in which other higher order programming constructs are used?

- Encryption algorithm implementation

My question is **NOT**:

- How do I use small bits of functionality without creating a whole function to do so?
- How do I replicate error handling functionality without copy/paste?

Comment: I once solved a question where goto was needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244617/data-grouping-according-to-relevant-values-in-sql-server/7254163#7254163

Comment: @t-clausen.dk That definitely needs to be listed as an answer!  It is an interesting and unique use of GOTO for sure!  Any thoughts on why you didn't use a while loop?

Comment: that could have been also done with `WHILE` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I almost never use `GOTO` and can easily live without it.

The one case where I would consider using it is when I have complicated code that does lots of error checking. I might want to take some action when an error returns, and `GOTO` allows me to define a single block of code for the error checking.

You can solve this problem in multiple ways, but `GOTO` is a reasonable option that guarantees that errors are processed consistently and the code is not cluttered with a lot of `if @Error = 0 . . .` statements.

Comment: I assume what you refer to here is catastrophic error handling for things like 5 statements that might fail and if any of them fail just use a single error handling block.

Comment: It seems like this situation is mostly avoidable now with the try - catch semantics available in newer iterations of SQL Server.  @Gordon Linoff, have you compared the two methods?

Comment: @NormanH . . . `try/catch` blocks don't replace `GOTO` and error handling.  The error handling code is essentially "exit" code for the stored procedure, say to log errors when one is found.  The `try/catch` block catches the error (and might process it, but the point of common error processing code is to avoid repeating the same code over and over).

Answer (score 2):

i saw goto a few times in large scripts where people used it to improve readability. sometimes it is better readable but mostly it turns into spaghetti code.

i see just one situation where goto can maybe perform better. its inside a multiple while loop. you can use goto once instead of multiple [breaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms181271.aspx) which just exists the innermost loop. nevertheless in my opinion break is not much better than goto, its both not a good programming style.

```
while ...
  while ...
    while... 
    break
  break
break


while ...
  while ...
    while... 
    goto endloops

endloops:
```

Comment: That's a great answer and a unique approach.  Certainly guarding against spaghetti code is a challenge - but that can happen even with full use of functions!

Answer (score 0):

I've used GOTO statements mainly when SSIS was not available (don't ask!!) to provide some control flow to a large stored procedure used for ETL processing. That's the only time I've ever used them and while useful in that scenario, it's obviously not a scenario you'd be in.

Answer (score 0):

One legitimate use might be when you have a complex stored procedure with multiple return points and want some common exit code.  In this example the `Exit:` label is always the last block of code in the procedure, so there's no jumping back up the procedure, which is when things can get difficult to follow.

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DoSomething
AS
    BEGIN
        IF <Logical Test1>
            GOTO Exit
        
        IF <Logical Test2>
            GOTO Exit
        
        IF <Logical Test3>
            GOTO Exit
        
        .....
        ..... 
        <Complex procedure logic> 
        .....
        .....
        
        Exit:
        ROLLBACK/COMMIT
        <Log proc call maybe>
        <Some other exit logic>
    END
```